# How to disable gcp services by using python (client library files)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I can able to disable GCP services via gcloud by using `gcloud services disable storage.googleapis.com`. but i need to achieve via **python client library files** ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference)), I searched but no luck. For Authentication i have credentials.json file. do we have any way ? can any one suggest me the code or reference document or site pl?

Comment: You were in the correct place. The client is https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/serviceusage/latest/google.cloud.service_usage_v1.services.service_usage.ServiceUsageClient There are often two different libraries. Refer to @CaioT answer for the other library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you referenced the wrong documentation, here is the Python SDK documentation you should look at: https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/serviceusage_v1.services.html#disable

Something similar as below (haven't tested it):

```py
client = discovery.build('serviceusage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
svc_name = "projects/123/services/serviceusage.googleapis.com"
operation = client.services().disable(name=svc_name).execute()
```

Comment: it working fine thanks bro