# How to disable GCP services via python client library files?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

here is reference  [**doc1**](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/disable) , [**doc2**](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/serviceusage/latest/google.cloud.service_usage_v1.types.DisableServiceRequest)

```
import google.auth
from google.cloud import servicemanagement_v1,service_usage_v1


credentials,project = google.auth.default()
req = {
    'name' : 'projects/123/services/monitoring.googleapis.com',
    'disable_dependent_services': True,
    # 'check_if_service_has_usage': service_usage_v1.types.DisableServiceRequest.check_if_service_has_usage
}
ok = service_usage_v1.ServiceUsageClient().disable_service(request=req)
print('disabled succesfuly')
```

If i enabled **check_if_service_has_usage** its througing error like (`AttributeError: type object 'DisableServiceRequest' has no attribute 'check_if_service_has_usage'` )

I need to know how to handle **check_if_service_has_usage** in my code is like bool?
then i also need to know when to use True/False for **disable_dependent_services**

Comment: What's your dependency version?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I couldn't  get u.  dependency version means ?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere do u mean ? this [link] (https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/)

Comment: No, this one: https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-service-usage/

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, correct  the same version  i am using, as u mentioned above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable gcp services by using python (client library files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595654/how-to-disable-gcp-services-by-using-python-client-library-files)

Comment: @rriovall tqq soo much